# Good resources about unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

Is there any good book or material which covers C# unit testing using mocks in depth?

Answer (score 9):

How about [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/). This is .NET specific, and should be fairly up to date.

Answer (score 8):

There is a rather good book describing how to use **NUnit** and **NMock** to do C# unit testing:

[Pragmatic Unit Testing in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977616673)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of documents on the nmock web site:

http://www.nmock.org/tutorial.html
http://www.nmock.org/advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following articles (especially the first one) from Stephen Walter pretty useful.

http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/06/11/tdd-introduction-to-moq.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/03/22/tdd-introduction-to-rhino-mocks.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/03/16/tdd-introduction-to-typemock-isolator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Extreme Programming Adventures in C#](http://www.microsoft.com/MSPress/books/6777.aspx) is well rated and deals with Mock Objects. It could be a bit outdated (current edition is 2004).

Answer (score 0):

also there is a video Course 
http://www.udemy.com/tdd-in-net-with-roy-osherove?from=aout

TDD Masterclass in .NET with Roy Osherove
Over 14 lectures and 9.5 hrs of content! for 79$